# Kubernetes failed on CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have an error in my Kubernetes cluster that seems weird.

I have a few pods that for some reason are stuck in `CrashLoopBackOff` state ( it is changing every time I try to install it from scratch )

when I try to do docker logs on the pod I get this error:
`standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

I read that it means the docker-entrypoint is not good but after 3-4 times of retries ( each retry I scale down the deployment , delete the image , pulls it back from registry and scales up ) it works on it's own.

if I pull the same image to a different docker host and tried `docker run -it <id> /bin/bash` it works.

I tried to save it :
`docker save 01b2a03cb2a4 > /dev/null && echo 'OK' || echo 'Corrupted'`

and I get corrupted:
`Error response from daemon: file integrity checksum failed for "/Dockerfile"`

any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

you can try those images.

```
# docker rmi
```

use this command to remove images.
and pull new images.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to solve `CrashLoopBackOff`.
Maybe your pod is executing a CMD which ends or exits, so, try adding to your Dockerfile:

```
#Dockerfile 
[...] 
CMD exec /bin/bash -c "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"
```

Second, post your Dockerfile to know this integrity error, please, and I'll edit this.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response , I found out that for some reason some of the times the docker images is pulled from the docker registry when the entry point file is 0 KB so the exec is failing. when I pull it from a regular docker machine without kubernenets the image pulls ok. any idea why ?